# Dear moderators, how shall I reword my question so it is not opinion-based anymore

Tags: support

I have never used meta, so I hope I am doing this right ...

My problem lies with this question: [Prototyping tool that allows independent scrolling of items](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/110292/prototyping-tool-that-allows-independent-scrolling-of-items/)

It has been put on hold for being "opinion based".

I don't see how this question is supposed to be opinion-based. I did not ask for "the best" tool to do the job, but rather if such a tool exists. I would really like to reword the question in a way that it will not be opinion based, however I do not know how I should reword it so that it does not fall under "opinion based".

I know that asking for advice on programs is always a touchy subject, but I did my best to not ask for any kind of personal opinion but rather just for the mere existence of such tools, and I think this site should not avoid every kind of subjects that involve asking for tools only because it might trigger some opinion. How else are we supposed to ask for advice on tools?

Maybe I am completely wrong. I will delete the question if it cannot be reworded, but I would like to maybe try to reword it first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is requesting recommendations for products. There is no correct answer to such questions, because new products come along all the time, new features are added / removed from existing products, some products may do things better than others...

These type of questions are referred to across the whole Stack Exchange network as a '**Shopping Request**' post. A blog post about such questions was written a while ago that is referenced quite a bit too:

[Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

That post should give you more information about why such questions aren't really suitable, and also some suggestions as to how to reword the post in a way that may be more suitable.

Comment: I see. I am sadly still unsure how I shall reword my question or if it even is possible. I will therefore remove the question.